# Golang - Customer Unmarshaler/Marshaler on pointer with nil/null value

Tags: go

## Golang - Customer Unmarshaler/Marshaler on pointer with nil/null value

I'm trying to implement custom `UnmarshalJSON` and `MarshalJSON` on pointer type, however none of this function is called when data from json is `null/nil` like in example below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    B *B `json:"b,omitempty"`
}

type B int

// Only for displaying value instead of
// pointer address when calling `fmt.Println`
func (b *B) String() string {
    if b == nil {
        return "nil"
    }

    return fmt.Sprintf("%d", *b)
}

// This function is not triggered when json
// data contains null instead of number value
func (b *B) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    fmt.Println("UnmarshalJSON on B called")

    var value int
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &value); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if value == 7 {
        *b = B(3)
    }

    return nil
}

// This function is not triggered when `B`
// is pointer type and has `nil` value
func (b *B) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    fmt.Println("MarshalJSON on B called")

    if b == nil {
        return json.Marshal(0)
    }

    if *b == 3 {
        return json.Marshal(7)
    }

    return json.Marshal(*b)
}

func main() {
    var a A

    // this won't call `UnmarshalJSON`
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{ "b": null }`), &a)
    fmt.Printf("a: %+v\n", a)

    // this won't call `MarshalJSON`
    b, _ := json.Marshal(a)
    fmt.Printf("b: %s\n\n", string(b))

    // this would call `UnmarshalJSON`
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{ "b": 7 }`), &a)
    fmt.Printf("a: %+v\n", a)

    // this would call `MarshalJSON`
    b, _ = json.Marshal(a)
    fmt.Printf("b: %s\n\n", string(b))
}
```

output:

```bash
a: {B:nil}
b: {}

UnmarshalJSON on B called
a: {B:3}
MarshalJSON on B called
b: {"b":7}
```

#### My questions are:

- why `UnmarshalJSON/MarshalJSON` is not called with `null/nil` value on pointer type
- how we can call `UnmarshalJSON/MarshalJSON` everytime when data is `null/nil` and type is a pointer instead of implementing `UnmarshalJSON/MarshalJSON` on `A` type and modify `b` property from level of `A`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but after removing `omitempty` `UnmarshalJSON/MarshalJSON` still aren't called with `null/nil` values

Comment: So the marshaler/unmarhaler is not even calling the method if the value is a null. In that case, I suppose your only option is to declare the struct with json.RawMessage, and deal with it after you unmarshal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Short**

Currently, unmarshaling/marshaling a Go struct will emit only the non-zero fields, since `nil pointer` is one [zero value in Go](https://go.dev/ref/spec#The_zero_value), the `UnmarshalJSON/MarshalJSON` is not called in this case.

---

Also, it seems there are some related proposals

- [proposal: encoding/json: add omitzero option](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45669)
- [proposal: encoding/json: allow returning nil from MarshalJSON to omit the field](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/50480)

However, there is no solution to resolve it now.

---

**Per code** [Unmarshalers](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/encoding/json/decode.go#L118)

> Unmarshalers implement UnmarshalJSON([]byte("null")) as a no-op

```golang
// By convention, to approximate the behavior of Unmarshal itself,
// Unmarshalers implement UnmarshalJSON([]byte("null")) as a no-op.
type Unmarshaler interface {
    UnmarshalJSON([]byte) error
}
```